# How to chunk List<Object> in Netty

Tags: java, netty, netty-socketio

When sending file, you can do `ctx.writeAndFlush(new ChunkedFile(new File("file.png")));`.

how about a `List<Object>`?

The list contains `String` and `bytes of image`.

from the documentation there's `ChunkedInput()` but I'm not able to get the use of it.

**UPDATE**

let's say in my Handler, inside `channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object o)` method where I want to send the `List<Object>` I've done the following

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object o) throws Exception {

   List<Object> msg = new ArrayList<>();

   /**getting the bytes of image**/
   byte[] imageInByte;
   BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
   // convert BufferedImage to byte array
   ByteArrayOutputStream bAoS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ImageIO.write(originalImage, "png", bAoS);
   bAoS.flush();
   imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
   baos.close();

   msg.clear();
   msg.add(0, "String"); //add the String into List
   msg.add(1, imageInByte); //add the bytes of images into list

   /**Chunk the List<Object> and Send it just like the chunked file**/
   ctx.writeAndFlush(new ChunkedInput(DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_DO_HERE)); //

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just implement your own `ChunkedInput<ByteBuf>`. Following the implementations shipped with Netty you can implement it as follows:

```
public class ChunkedList implements ChunkedInput<ByteBuf> {
    private static final byte[] EMPTY = new byte[0];
    private byte[] previousPart = EMPTY;
    private final int chunkSize;
    private final Iterator<Object> iterator;

    public ChunkedList(int chunkSize, List<Object> objs) {
        //chunk size in bytes
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
        this.iterator = objs.iterator();
    }


    public ByteBuf readChunk(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        return readChunk(ctx.alloc());
    }

    public ByteBuf readChunk(ByteBufAllocator allocator) {
        if (isEndOfInput())
            return null;
        else {
            ByteBuf buf = allocator.buffer(chunkSize);
            boolean release = true;
            try {
                int bytesRead = 0;
                if (previousPart.length > 0) {
                    if (previousPart.length > chunkSize) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException();
                    }
                    bytesRead += previousPart.length;
                    buf.writeBytes(previousPart);
                }
                boolean done = false;
                while (!done) {
                    if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
                        done = true;
                        previousPart = EMPTY;
                    } else {
                        Object o = iterator.next();
                        //depending on the encoding
                        byte[] bytes = o instanceof String ? ((String) o).getBytes() : (byte[]) o;
                        bytesRead += bytes.length;
                        if (bytesRead > chunkSize) {
                            done = true;
                            previousPart = bytes;
                        } else {
                            buf.writeBytes(bytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
                release = false;
            } finally {
                if (release)
                    buf.release();
            }
            return buf;
        }
    }

    public long length() {
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean isEndOfInput() {
        return !iterator.hasNext() && previousPart.length == 0;
    }

    public long progress() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void close(){
        //close
    }
}
```

In order to write `ChunkedContent` there is a special handler shipped with `Netty`. See `io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler`. So just add to your downstream. Here is the quote from documentation:

> A `ChannelHandler` that adds support for writing a large data stream
>   asynchronously neither spending a lot of memory nor getting
>   `OutOfMemoryError`. Large data streaming such as file transfer requires
>   complicated state management in a `ChannelHandler` implementation.
>   `ChunkedWriteHandler` manages such complicated states so that you can
>   send a large data stream without difficulties.

Comment: Just a note... if you want to send a file and not need to manipulate its content in the pipeline you should really use `DefaultFileRegion` as it will allow you to use `sendfile(...)` a.k.a zero-copy file transfer.

Comment: @St.Antario - Thank you for answering my question! I really appreciate it and I think your answer could give me the solution, I really don't get the use of  `ChunkedInput() `, so can you please make it more clear for me? I already update my question, inside my Handler, in `channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object o) ` how can I use your given solution? Thank you so much!

Comment: @St.Antario - Thank you so much! Still, I don't get it, XD, but let me try to read the documentation again and try your solution, I really appreciate your help! thanks! I'll update you later, Thank you so much!

Comment: @Polar replace `new ChunkedInput(DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_DO)` with `new ChukedList(msg, 1024)`. It will chunk your content by 1024 bytes.

Comment: @St.Antario - Yo! Thanks for every response! By the way, from the Server where I want to receive the List Object, I'm still getting `io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 1048576: 1399157370 - discarded` error. . . do you have any idea?

Comment: Also, I'm getting error of `io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultChannelPromise@ee834e(incomplete)` from the Client where I'm sending the List Object. maybe this happen because the Client being disconnected from the Server due to `io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 1048576: 1399157370 - discarded` error...

Comment: I give up. . . I'm having a hard time understanding this library. . . :( I now using `ServerSocket` and `Socket` from my old project. Thank you.